# Snakemake partial expand, using one output file per execution in the following rule

Tags: python, bash, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am having troubles trying to execute the final rule in my Snakefile once for each input I provide it. It currently uses a [partial expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398091/how-to-do-a-partial-expand-in-snakemake) to fill one value, seen in `rule download`.

However, when using the `expand` function, the rule sees the input as a single list of strings, and is executed one time. I would like to have three executions of the rule, with the input being one string for each, so the downloads are able to happen in parallel.

Here is the Snakefile I am using:

**Snakefile**

```python
import csv

def get_tissue_name():
    tissue_data = []
    with open("master_init.csv", "r") as rfile:
        reader = csv.reader(rfile)
        for line in reader:
            id = line[1].split("_")[0]  # naiveB_S1R1 -> naiveB
            tissue_data.append(id)

    return tissue_data


def get_tag_data():
    tag_data = []
    with open("master_init.csv", "r") as rfile:
        reader = csv.reader(rfile)
        for line in reader:
            tag = line[1].split("_")[-1]
            tag_data.append(tag)  # example: S1R1

    return tag_data


rule all:
    input:
        # Execute distribute & download
        expand(os.path.join("output","{tissue_name}"),
               tissue_name=get_tissue_name())

rule distribute:
    input: "master_init.csv"
    output: "init/{tissue_name}_{tag}.csv"
    params:
        id = "{tissue_name}_{tag}"
    run:
        lines = open(str(input), "r").readlines()
        wfile = open(str(output), "w")

        for line in lines:
            line = line.rstrip()  # remove trailing newline

            # Only write line if the output file has the current 
            # tissue-name_tag (naiveB_S1R1) in the file name
            if params.id in line:
                wfile.write(line)

        wfile.close()

rule download:
    input: expand("init/{tissue_name}_{tag}.csv", 
                  tag=get_tag_data(), allow_missing=True)
    output: directory(os.path.join("output", "{tissue_name}"))
    shell:
        """
        while read srr name endtype; do
            fastq-dump --split-files --gzip $srr --outdir {output}
        done < {input}
        """
```

When I execute this Snakefile, I get the following output:

```bash
> snakemake --cores 1 --dry-run

Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job           count    min threads    max threads
----------  -------  -------------  -------------
all               1              1              1
distribute        3              1              1
download          1              1              1
total             5              1              1


[Wed Sep  1 15:28:27 2021]
rule distribute:
    input: master_init.csv
    output: init/naiveB_S1R1.csv
    jobid: 2
    wildcards: tissue_name=naiveB, tag=S1R1
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/sr/gzlz2wcs5tz1jns1j13m57jr0000gn/T

[Wed Sep  1 15:28:27 2021]
Finished job 2.
1 of 5 steps (20%) done

[Wed Sep  1 15:28:27 2021]
rule distribute:
    input: master_init.csv
    output: init/naiveB_S1R2.csv
    jobid: 3
    wildcards: tissue_name=naiveB, tag=S1R2
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/sr/gzlz2wcs5tz1jns1j13m57jr0000gn/T

[Wed Sep  1 15:28:27 2021]
Finished job 3.
2 of 5 steps (40%) done

[Wed Sep  1 15:28:27 2021]
rule distribute:
    input: master_init.csv
    output: init/naiveB_S1R3.csv
    jobid: 4
    wildcards: tissue_name=naiveB, tag=S1R3
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/sr/gzlz2wcs5tz1jns1j13m57jr0000gn/T

[Wed Sep  1 15:28:27 2021]
Finished job 4.
3 of 5 steps (60%) done

[Wed Sep  1 15:28:27 2021]
rule download:
    input: init/naiveB_S1R1.csv, init/naiveB_S1R2.csv, init/naiveB_S1R3.csv
    output: output/naiveB
    jobid: 1
    wildcards: tissue_name=naiveB
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/sr/gzlz2wcs5tz1jns1j13m57jr0000gn/T

/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `init/naiveB_S1R2.csv'
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: `        done < init/naiveB_S1R1.csv init/naiveB_S1R2.csv init/naiveB_S1R3.csv'
[Wed Sep  1 15:28:27 2021]
Error in rule download:
    jobid: 1
    output: output/naiveB
    shell:

        while read srr name endtype; do
            fastq-dump --split-files --gzip $srr --outdir output/naiveB
        done < init/naiveB_S1R1.csv init/naiveB_S1R2.csv init/naiveB_S1R3.csv

        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: /Users/joshl/PycharmProjects/FastqToGeneCounts/exampleSnakefile/.snakemake/log/2021-09-01T152827.234141.snakemake.log
```

I am getting an error in the execution of `rule download` because of the `done < {input}` portion. The entirety of the input is being used to read from, as opposed to single files. In an ideal execution, `rule download` would execute three separate times, once for each input file.

A simple fix is to wrap the `while . . . done` section in a for loop, but then I lose the ability to download multiple SRR files at the same time.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot execute a single rule multiple times for the same output. In your `rule download` output depends only on *tissue_name*, and doesn't depend on *tag*.

You have a choice: either to provide a filename that depends on tag as an output (like the filename you are downloading), or create a loop in the rule itself.